# How do I copy a csv file with 2 columns but multiple values with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have an .csv file that includes **2 colums** which are **ID** and their **related segments**.

[image: It looks like this]

But I have nearly 600 thousand rows. In that rows **segmentID** column has just one value. But in other row there is m**ore than one value** and **it changes**.

[image]

I have tried to copy the values to my database with this code:

`**COPY FROM** 'C:/User/Local/intersectionsegments.csv' **DELIMITER** ',' **CSV HEADER**`

But my method takes just one value for **segmentID** and one value for **IntersectingSegments**
How can I upload my csv file to the database with a query.

Comment: So you can have more then one value for each `segmentID`. From the screenshot it looks like those values are in their own columns. If that is the case you will need to include those columns in your table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes sir, you are right. For the **IntersectingSegments** column there are more than one values but in another cells. How can I detect automaticly these seperated cells and added under the **IntersectingSegments** column.

Comment: That would either have to be done in spreadsheet or via an external program that concatenates the values.  `COPY` won't do that on the fly unless you pull the values in via a `PROGRAM` instead of a file, per instructions here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is why CSV are poor sources of data (unavoidable sources, but still poor). The easiest process here is to create an intermediate staging table. This table contains as many columns as the CSV. Use COPY to populate this table and sql to copy from stage table to your production table. Something along the lines of

```
Create table intersecting_seqments_stage
           ( segment_id  integer
           , segment_1   integer
           , segment_2   integer
           , ...
           , segment_n   integer
           ) ;
```

Now with that in place, run the following as a script:

```
truncate intersecting_seqments_stage;
copy intersecting_seqments_stage from 'csv_table_name' ...;
insert into intersecting_seqments(segment_id, intersecting_seqment)
   select segment_id, intersecting_segment 
     from (select segment_id, segment_1 as intersecting_segment
             from intersecting_seqments_stage
           union all
           select segment_id, segment_2  
             from intersecting_seqments_stage
           union all  
           ...
           select segment_id, segment_n  
             from intersecting_seqments_stage
         )
   where intersecting_segment is not null;
```